# How to create a tabbed box using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'd like to create a new style in TikZ for nodes with transparent background, rounded corners, with labels oriented vertically on their left on a opaque fill (similar to a tabbed paper). A sample sketch is given below. The "Label" will be given to the style as parameter.

[image: tabbed box]

Comment: You're pretty good at sketching. ;-)

Comment: @PaulGessler, I first sketched one by hand, it looked terrible though =P

Comment: I feel like this is a job better suited to `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`, both of which are based on TikZ (AFAIK).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution with Tikz since you were asking for it. I basically defined a new command with four arguments:

```
 \tabb{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
```

1. Position of the node
2. Color (the second color will automatically be lighter than the label)
3. Label text
4. Main text

I changed the `x` and `y` of the tikzpicture above for making it easier for me to place the examples.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\tikzset{
    rect/.style={%
        draw,%  
        line width=.4pt,
        rounded corners,                 
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split part fill={#1,none},
        every text node part/.style={text=white, font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
    } 
}

\newcommand{\tabb}[4]{
    \node[rect=#2] (a) at (#1) {\rotatebox{90}{#3}\nodepart{two}#4};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \fill[#2!30, rounded corners] (a.south west) rectangle (a.north east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}    
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=1.5cm]

\tabb{1,1}{blue}{Label}{bla bla}
\tabb{1,0}{red}{Label}{bla bla}
\tabb{0,1}{green}{Label}{bla bla}
\tabb{0,0}{orange}{Label}{bla bla}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

[image]

The code (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{bluebg}{RGB}{201,218,248}
\definecolor{bluelabel}{RGB}{0,0,255}

\newtcbox{\labelbox}{
  enhanced,
  nobeforeafter,
  tcbox raise base,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  top=0.4cm,
  bottom=0.4cm,
  right=0pt,
  left=4mm,
  arc=5pt,
  boxsep=2pt,
  before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=bluelabel!50!black,
  coltext=black,
  colback=bluebg,
  overlay={
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
      \fill[bluelabel] (frame.south west)
      rectangle 
      node[
        text=white,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize,
        rotate=90] {LABEL} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\labelbox{some test text}

\end{document}
```

### Update

Now the label is given as an argument, there are two optional arguments: the first one, controlling attributes for the main part of the box, and the second one, controlling the color for the label background. I illustrate the example of the `remember as` key to be used to reference the boxes in a `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{bluebg}{RGB}{201,218,248}
\definecolor{bluelabel}{RGB}{0,0,255}

\DeclareTCBox{\mylib}{O{}mO{}}{
  enhanced,
  nobeforeafter,
  tcbox raise base,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  top=0.4cm,
  bottom=0.4cm,
  right=0pt,
  left=4mm,
  arc=5pt,
  boxsep=2pt,
  before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=bluelabel!50!black,
  coltext=black,
  colback=bluebg,
  overlay={
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
      \fill[bluelabel,#3] 
        (frame.south west)
        rectangle 
        node[
          text=white,
          font=\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize,
          rotate=90
        ] {#2} 
        ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}
  },
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\mylib[remember as=box1]{Label1}{some test text for box1}\qquad
\mylib[remember as=box2,colback=orange!40]{Label2}[red]{text for box2}
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  line width=3pt,
  shorten >= 3pt,
  shorten <= 3pt,
  ]
\draw[->,red!75!black] 
  (box1.north) to[bend left] (box2.north);
\draw[->,green!75!black] 
  (box2.south) to[bend left] (box1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Gonzalo. Can I use this inside a TikZ picture with other elements in there?

Comment: @Ali Sure. I updated my answer with an example referencing boxes in a `tikzpicture`, but you could use them directly too.

Comment: @Ali But if you are planning to use this as kind of a node, the answer by 
John Kormylo might be a better option.

Answer (score 6):

The `\parbox` isn't really needed, but I wasn't sure if one could specify the text widths for each part separately.

```
\documentclass[border=.1in]{standalone}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,rounded corners,rectangle split parts=2,
  draw,rectangle split part fill={blue,LightBlue}]
  {\rotatebox{90}{\color{white}Label}
  \nodepart{two}
  \parbox{1in}{text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: split node]